# How can I manipulate the command line through VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

Could anyone give me example code to access the command line through VBScript? I want to execute two commands respectively in a command prompt.

For example, first command: `cd C:\a`, second command: `winzip32.exe -min -a D:\d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your commands in a .cmd or .bat file and then run that. You could even build the batch file inside your script if it is not static.

**MyBatch.cmd**

```
CD C:\a
winzip32.exe -min -a D:\d
```

**MyScript.vbs**

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "MyBatch.cmd"
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [wshell.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a%28VS.85%29.aspx). The other one is [wshell.exec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: but can it be used to run certain set of commands rather than just launching an application?

Comment: if you use it in a loop, yes.